# Phonegap (Cordova). If I double-click Return button then app crashes

Tags: android, cordova

If I double-click "Return" button on my Android device then app crashes.

My application built using JQuery Mobile and Phonegap 2.0 (Cordova).

I've faced with the issue. 
I put the focus to any INPUT field on the page so keyboard appears. 
I double-click on "Return" button on my device. 
Expected: app returning to the previous page I've visited to. 
Actual: app crashes

Eclipse Log Cat showing me next message when it happens:

```
11-09 18:20:04.175: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7399): Ignore this event
11-09 18:20:04.597: D/dalvikvm(136): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 11% free 15278K/17159K, paused 149ms
11-09 18:20:04.632: D/CordovaWebView(7399): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-09 18:20:04.675: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(7399): Ignore this event
11-09 18:20:04.707: W/InputManagerService(136): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub

$Proxy@414c0dc0 (uid=10008 pid=7399)
11-09 18:20:04.707: W/InputManagerService(136): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub

$Proxy@414c0dc0 (uid=10008 pid=7399)
11-09 18:20:04.711: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7399): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-09 18:20:04.925: D/OpenGLRenderer(7399): Flushing caches (mode 0)
11-09 18:20:04.988: D/dalvikvm(202): GC_CONCURRENT freed 869K, 32% free 10761K/15623K, paused 2ms+22ms
11-09 18:20:05.425: D/OpenGLRenderer(7399): Flushing caches (mode 1)
11-09 18:20:05.429: D/DroidGap(7399): onDestroy()
11-09 18:20:05.429: D/CordovaWebView(7399): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-09 18:20:05.433: D/CordovaWebView(7399): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-09 18:20:05.457: D/DroidGap(7399): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
11-09 18:20:05.476: D/Cordova(7399): onPageFinished(about:blank)
11-09 18:20:05.476: D/DroidGap(7399): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
11-09 18:20:05.476: D/DroidGap(7399): onMessage(exit,null)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the actual crash logs and your code

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue. 
Solution is to update Phonegap to version 2.2 and bind "blur" for all "input" text fields on the backbutton event.
Thanks everybody for your time.

Comment: I've resolved this issue. 
Solution is to update Phonegap to version 2.2 and bind "blur" for all "input" text fields on the backbutton event.
Thanks everybody for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The button at the top left hand corner of the page is the UP button, not Back, if I interpret this correctly. It should be your app's icon with a left angle bracket.
See [Implementing Ancestral Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS as the fix : It solved the problem for me.

```
input {
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only
}
```